# Extract quarter information from numpy datetime64 obkect

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, datetime

I have below `numpy` `datetime64` object

```
import numpy as np
date_time = np.datetime64('2012-05-01T01:00:00.000000+0100')
```

I would like to express this in YearQuarter i.e. `'2012Q2'`. Is there any method available to perform this? I tried with `pandas Timestamp` method but it generates error:

```
import pandas as pd
>>> pd.Timestamp(date_time).dt.quarter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'dt'
```

Any pointer will be very helpful

Comment: `pd.Timestamp(date_time).to_period('Q')`

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways that one can achieve that, depending on the desired output type.

If one wants the type `pandas._libs.tslibs.period.Period`, then one can use:

- [`pandas.Period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Period.html) as follows

  ```
  year_quarter = pd.Period(date_time, freq='Q')

  [Out]: 2012Q2
  ```
- [`pandas.Timestamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html), as [user7864386 mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72192727/extract-quarter-information-from-numpy-datetime64-obkect#comment127552014_72192727), as follows

  ```
  year_quarter = pd.Timestamp(date_time).to_period('Q')

  [Out]: 2012Q2
  ```

Alternatively, if one wants the final output to be a string, one will have to pass [`pandas.Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html), more specifically `.strftime('%YQ%q')`, such as

```
year_quarter = pd.Period(date_time, freq='Q').strftime('%YQ%q')

# or

year_quarter = pd.Timestamp(date_time).to_period('Q').strftime('%YQ%q')
```

---

**Notes:**

- `date_time = np.datetime64('2012-05-01T01:00:00.000000+0100')` gives a

> DeprecationWarning: parsing timezone aware datetimes is deprecated; this will raise an error in the future

- To check the variable `year_quarter` type, one can do the following

  ```
  print(type(year_quarter))
  ```